# Entity Framework Code First Migration Error

Tags: .net, entity-framework, exception, ef-code-first

I'm new to MVC 4 and entity framework and when I run this command from the package manager console:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MyFirstMvcApp.Models.InventoryDbContext
```

Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

I get the following error:

```
Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At D:\GitProjects\MyFirstMvcApp\trunk\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0-alpha2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:363 char:27
+     $toolsPath = Join-Path <<<<  $installPath tools
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At D:\GitProjects\MyFirstMvcApp\trunk\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0-alpha2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:392 char:73
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path <<<<  $toolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll))
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\GitProjects\MyFirstMvcApp\trunk\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0-alpha2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:393 char:50
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CreateInstance:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At D:\GitProjects\MyFirstMvcApp\trunk\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0-alpha2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:426 char:19
+         (Join-Path <<<<  $runner.ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll),
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
```

How do I fix this?
Note that I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with SP1 and I have installed MVC4 in this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MVC4VS2010_Loc).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Fixed it by uninstalling and re-installing entity framework.
For the benefit of others, here are the commands...

Uninstall:

> PM> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force

After uninstalling, reinstall EntityFramework:

> PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre

There! It's fixed. Though I still don't know what caused the problem.

Comment: `PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre -Version 5.0.0`

for specific version

Comment: some comment: You must run your VS in "as Administrator" mode

Answer (score 22):

Visual studio 2019:
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force

then

Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre -Version 6.2.0

something is up with v6.3.0

Comment: As of v6.3.0 reverting back to v6.2.0 is also the only way I have gotten around this error. It happens in both vs2017 and vs2019 it must be relate to @antoine answer above.

Answer (score 13):

I was facing the same issue this is how I solved the issue,

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and hence I installed latest Entity framework 6.3.0(stable) I was facing the issue when I run the Enable-Migrations command, I tried to re-install the Entity framework but it didn't work so I have installed the old version 6.2.0 from the Nuget package manger apparently it turned out working.

Answer (score 13):

Tried all the things here. I personally hate solving things without knowing what the problem is in the first place. Digging down in forums this seems to be a known bug caused in version 6.3.0 when the startup project is a web app. They have already fixed it in their daily builds. So to solve it you need to install that.

First, uninstall the package:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
```

Then install the latest daily build (in my case the following one)

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.4.0-preview1-19506-01
```

Comment: rolling back to 6.2.0 also works, but this answer should be higher up. thanks for investigating.

Comment: You are completely right @SedatKapanoglu , since the problem happens on 6.3.0 on those specific conditions, downgrading or upgrading should solve the issue. I imagine that my solution will also get out of date soon with the final release of 6.4.0

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu mr sedet, is downgrading to a final release better than upgrading to a preview release?

Answer (score 5):

I came across this issue while upgrading to EntityFramework "6.3.0" from "6.2.0". The issue and workaround can be found here [EF 6.3.0 PMC commands throw `ParameterBindingValidationException` when Startup Project is a Web App](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/1290).

The problem arises when you have multiple projects and you set an ASP.NET project as the Startup project

Workaround suggested by the link:

> If you added a new dummy console app to the solution and installed the daily build of the EntityFramework into it, that version of the commands which includes the fix would be used. The commands would work just fine with projects referencing EF 6.3.

Personal Solution:

Setting the Startup project to a non ASP.NET project fixed the issue in my case. Note that you will have to copy the connection strings to the relevant project's configuration file if you're using them.

Answer (score 4):

Some years later...
Another possible reason for this issue is the VS 2017 csproj format - or better said, the PackageReference approach in contrast to using packages.config.

With the new approach to include Nuget Packages using the PackageReference format in your project files, the install script of EntityFramework is not being executed (it is a known fact for this new approach of including nuget packages). Due to that fact, the PowerShell commands are not being ready for execution.

There is an ongoing discussion on that issue on the [Entity Framework GitHub repository](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/189).
Until this is fixed (either by the NuGet people or the EF people) in order for migrations to run (talking of EF 6 - not EF Core!) you need to stick to the "old" way of including Nuget packages using the packages.config approach.

Check your Visual Studio settings at
`Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> General` and make sure that the
`Default package management format` is set to `Packages.config`.

Note that you will have to uninstall all Packages, save the project, restart visual studio and afterwards re-install all packages when switching this setting.
In current Version of VS 2017 (I think from v 15.4 onwards) there is an automatic conversion from Packages.config to PackageReference, but not vice versa (unfortunately).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the `Startup Project`.

I have 5 project in the same solution and each time I `Right Click` and `Set as startup` to a non ASPNET CORE project, I get this kind of error.

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem when i updated EntityFramework to version 6.3.0 so when i went back to 6.2.0 it fixed the problem so i advice you to do the same

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling Entity Framework didn't work for me.

It turned out that it was not `Visual Studio` or `Entity Framemwork` casuing the problem, but it was the fact I was running `PowerShell 2` (on `Windows 7`).

`Entity Framework` and `Visual Studio` require `PowerShell 3`.

Following the update and reboot, the issue was gone. 
Hopefully this will help a few people.

You can find PowerShell here -> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855

Answer (score 1):

In my case none of the above solutions worked, so I had a quick look in the packages.config file and to my surprise found two entries for Entity Framework

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Note that they are different versions, not sure how this could actually happen. Anyway, once I removed the older one from the packages.config file i.e. ended up with just this one:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I could then Enable-Migrations with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem while working with Code First migrations.

What worked for me is go to NuGet packet manager, then search `Entity Framework`.
There I had installed the `Pre-release version`, then I selected the `Latest Stable version` and installed it.

Everything worked perfectly afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 6.3, the Entity Framework tooling supports the new SDK-style project format.

However, this issue can still happen when the project containing your migrations uses the new SDK-style format, while the startup project is using the classic csproj format.

To fix this, make both projects use the same csproj format.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this answer? I have Windows Forms projects using the pre Core csproj format, but I'm not sure what relevance this has to the problem.  I could find not reference to upgrade notes on the EF Github page, so I don't know what to think.

Comment: @andrensairr Sorry, I ended up just rolling back to 6.2. Although I did observe better behavior at the time when making both projects follow the same format, somehow later on the issue came back. I didn't bother investigating, I don't have time for it.

Answer (score 0):

Shared with above suggestions here's my addition.

PM> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
Then;

PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre

this two above actions not enough. I needed to do the next one:

Then in the Solution Explorer, create a class with the below code inside your project at root level - in my case. and then Migrations folder with Configurations.cs file in it created automatically.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
pubic MyDbContext()
{
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an additional thing that I found while having this issue.

As it turns out, in my case (Running Visual Studio 2017, Entity Framework 6.2) the issue was that the project was in a remote directory (\server\user\location) rather than a local directory.

Upon copying the project to a local location, the command runs without issue.