# .Net Core can't use Add-migrations with Docker support

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm stuck for using EF command with docker support on an ASP.NET Core project.

I created an ASP.NET Core API basic project using Visual Studio 2017 RC.

I added dependencies and configurations needed by Entity Framework to work.

I ran `Add-migration "name"` and `Update-database` and everything works fine as expected.

But since I added Docker support on the project, I receive the error below each time I run an EF command:

```
Add-migration : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.

 At line:1 char:1
+ Add-migration init-database
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Migration], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Add-Migration
```

As I saw on many tutorials, there is no need to update Docker file or Docker compose file in order to make EF commands available but maybe I'm wrong.

PS: Docker works pretty fine, I'm able to run the project through Docker without any problems. Since Docker support creates another project in the solution, I already tried to go on the app project path to run the command instead of solution path, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410987/entity-framework-code-first-migration-error

Comment: It's definitely not my case, i'm using Entity Framework Core with latest dotnet core on visual studio 2017 RC through Docker Support and as I said, I was able to add migration before the docker support was added. But i think, my problem is a bug related to visual studio 2017 RC and Docker support, as i tested the same scenario on visual studio 2015 and everythings works fine.

Comment: @BriceMolesti I have the same problem. Created new project with docker support and I've been getting this error also...

Comment: @Kryptoxx If you're still stuck on this problem, check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable docker support add the project "docker-compose" to the solution.

So just set your initial app project as the startup project fix the problem

Or run any EF Command with -startupproject "yourinitialappproject"